# How to concatenate pandas.DataFrames columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame called `raw_df`:

```
columns = ['force0', 'distance0', 'force1', 'distance1']

raw_data = [{'force0': 1.2, 'distance0': 0.0, 'force1': 0.5, 'distance1': 0.0},
            {'force0': 1.3, 'distance0': 0.1, 'force1': 0.6, 'distance1': 0.0},
            {'force0': 1.4, 'distance0': 0.2, 'force1': 0.7, 'distance1': 0.3},
            {'force0': 1.5, 'distance0': 0.5, 'force1': 0.8, 'distance1': 0.6}]

raw_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=columns)
```

`raw_df` looks like this:

```
   force0  distance0  force1  distance1
0     1.2        0.0     0.5        0.0
1     1.3        0.1     0.6        0.0
2     1.4        0.2     0.7        0.3
3     1.5        0.5     0.8        0.6
```

At the moment there is no index but I would like the distance columns to be combined into one index so the columns are then:

```
          force0  force1
distance                
0.0          1.2     0.5
0.0          NaN.    0.6
0.1          1.3     NaN
0.2          1.4     NaN
0.3          NaN     0.7
0.5          1.5     NaN
0.6          NaN     0.8
```

Note that there were 2 entries in force1 for distance1 = 0.0.

The index (distances) should NOT be sorted: they increase then decrease variably and the original order for each test is important.

Stefan posted an amazing answer to my poorly-described question but it seemed to fill in any missing forces with other numbers (which would be misleading because there were no force measurements for those distances in those tests). I have used `np.nan` for missing values as I think this is what `pandas` does.

I think that `merge` or `join` might do what I need but couldn't understand [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Perhaps `pandas.DataFrame` was not designed for such data, and I should use `numpy.genfromtxt` instead and just select the columns I need on the fly: I don't see any advantage to using a `pandas.DataFrame` if I'm selecting columns on the fly (because I'm not using an index in that case).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would be nice having a sample of your original dataframe to work with.

Comment: What are your `test_ids`? Are all the values in `Distances1`, `Distances2`, etc. unique?

Comment: test_ids is just a list of integers corresponding to the test numbers. For example, the first is 1 as in Forces 1

Comment: And are all the values in `Distances1`, `Distances2`, etc. unique?

Comment: The distances are not unique. Thanks for starting to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a [MultiIndex DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html):

1. Read each test into a separate DataFrame using `pd.read_csv()`
2. Combined the DataFrames into one using `df = pd.concat(frame_list, keys=test_names)`

Rather than write a long description here, I wrote [a Jupyter notebook](https://gist.github.com/blokeley/64f630bd78a3e5037061) on the subject comparing the MultiIndex method against just keeping a standard Python list of DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are starting from a situation similar to this:

```
columns = list(sum(list(zip(['Forces{}'.format(i) for i in range(4)], ['Distances{}'.format(i) for i in range(4)])), ()))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 11, size=(100, 8)), columns=columns)

   Forces0  Distances0  Forces1  Distances1  Forces2  Distances2  Forces3  \
0        3           5        8           3        7           4        2   
1        1           4       10           9        9           3        6   
2       10           3        1           3        3           7        8   
3        2           1        3           6       10          10       10   
4        4           2        9           1        3          10        8   

   Distances3  
0           8  
1           5  
2           3  
3           8  
4           8
```

and you are aiming to have the various `Distance` columns form a single `index` while the respective `Force` `columns remain in place. You could`stack` the frame like so:

```
df.set_index([c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('Force')], inplace=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=-1, drop=True).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'Distance'})
df.set_index(['Distance'], inplace=True)
```

to get:

```
          Forces0  Forces1  Forces2  Forces3
Distance                                    
9               7        4        6        7
9               7        4        6        7
1               7        4        6        7
6               7        4        6        7
5               1        2        3        1
```

Comment: Wow. That looks very good. I don't need the MultiIndex but otherwise looks right. I'll test it later tonight when my kids are in bed. Thanks

Comment: Is there a shortcut not to create the MultiIndex?

Comment: Updated so there's no `MultiIndex`. `.stack()` automatically creates the extra `column`, so I just dropped it.

Comment: Thanks. Some of the formatting may have been broken but it's not a problem. I'm intrigued by the magic string "level_4". Will test in about an hour

Comment: Thanks, fixed the formatting. No magic here - `.stack()` creates a `Series`, adding all `values` gathered from the `DataFrame` as `column` and creating a new `index` level with the `column` names, and creating a name for it. That's what you see after `reset_index()` - the name depends on the number of `levels` in the `index` prior to `.stack()` - ie, the number of `Force` `columns` set as `index` just prior. I've changed it so you don't have to rely on knowledge of the number of `Force` columns.